# Not able to run block in PostgreSQL 8.2

Tags: postgresql

I can't run this block in PostgreSQL 8.2.

```
DECLARE
        curtime char;
BEGIN
        curtime := 'now';
        INSERT INTO logtable VALUES (logtxt, curtime);
        RETURN curtime;
END;
```

When I try it shows the error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "char"
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to run a [PL/PgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) code block stand-alone, without wrapping it up in a function using [`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html). That won't work, you need to include it in a function or (from PostgreSQL 9.0) a [`DO` block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html). *PL/PgSQL and plain SQL are different languages* so you can't just run PL/PgSQL code directly.

It'd help if you explained *why* you're trying to write the code you pasted. I suspect you're trying to solve a problem that's better handled with a [trigger function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/triggers.html) like an [audit trigger](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger).

### Some important notes:

**You need to update PostgreSQL**: PostgreSQL 8.2 is dangerously out of date and [unsupported](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). security and bug fixes are no longer being released. Upgrade urgently to a supported version, but make sure to read the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html) for each major ".0" version like "8.3.0", "8.4.0", etc for migration and compatibility advice.

**Avoid `'now'`**: Also, instead of using `'now'` you should usually use the  [current date/time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), particularly `current_timestamp`.

**`current_timestamp` is stable**: The hoop-jumping you are doing is probably unnecessary because the value of `current_timestamp` (and `'now'::timestamp`) doesn't change for the duration of a transaction. Eg:

```
regress=# BEGIN;
regress=# SELECT current_timestamp;
 2012-08-14 14:52:43.382596+08
regress=# SELECT pg_sleep(5);
regress=# SELECT current_timestamp;
 2012-08-14 14:52:43.382596+08
```

### Details

Your intention appears to be something like the following (*incorrect, do not use*) code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(logtxt text) RETURNS timestamptz AS $$
DECLARE
        curtime char;
BEGIN
        curtime := 'now';
        INSERT INTO logtable VALUES (logtxt, curtime);
        RETURN curtime;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

but you've misused the `char` datatype, which requires a length parameter. It defaults to 1 if not supplied so you'll get:

```
regress=# SELECT some_function();
ERROR:  value too long for type character(1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "some_function" line 5 at assignment
```

*NEVER* use the `char` datatype in SQL; use `varchar` or `text`. For cross-database portability `varchar(n)` where `n` is a maximum length is required; if portability isn't needed use `text`.

If you change `char` to `text` in the above, your code might run, but it still doesn't make any sense. I strongly suspect that you really want to write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(logtxt text) RETURNS timestamptz AS $$
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO logtable VALUES (logtxt, current_timestamp);
        RETURN current_timestamp;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

... but you didn't know about the [current date/time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

Even that's too much, really. I think you're trying to solve a problem that's a better fit for a trigger.

Comment: @Jils2947 No worries. I've expanded the explanation considerably and added some links. Hope it helps. If not, please explain what you're trying to achieve with the code you posted - what problem you are trying to solve with it.