# Not able to run block in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

When I run the following query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function() RETURNS timestamptz AS $$ 
DECLARE         
   curtime timestamp; 
BEGIN    
   curtime := 'now';     
   INSERT INTO logtable VALUES (logtxt, curtime);    
   RETURN curtime; 
END;
```

The error showing is

> *ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$"*

Comment: As for your problem, you left the last line off: `$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';` because you copied and pasted it from my answer to your previous question, and I cut that line off when editing by accident. It'd be better to post a comment to ask about that.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of the function definition is missing. After `END;` there should be:

```
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That's because you copied it from my answer to your previous question:

[Not able to run block in PostgreSQL 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946736/not-able-to-run-block-in-postgresql-8-2)

and I made an editing mistake in my answer that cut that line off. I also had it correct in the later example and linked to the documentation that explains it all, so it looks like you've just copied and pasted it without trying to understand what is happening.

Please read [the documentation on PL/PgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html), but also think about *why* you are doing this. The code you've posted doesn't make much sense, and I suspect you are trying to solve a problem in a very backwards way. Try explaining what you are trying to achieve.

If you really must do this, try the code at the [end of my answer to your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946751/398670).

Comment: OK, it seems this question has previous context. I'm going to delete my answer to reduce information surplus (I think a read through the CREATE FUNCTION documentation would benefit @Jils2947 a lot).

Comment: @jpe Yep, reading wins over copy'n'paste coding in general. Of course, we both have the unfair advantage of English skills (at least in my case skills I got "for free" growing up with it as a 1st language); it's a lot harder to read documentation in English if you've grown up with another language.

Comment: Aside: `plpgsql` is a keyword in the declaration [`LANGUAGE plpgsql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) and does not have to be quoted.